# Correct algorithm to convert binary floating point "1101.11" into decimal (13.75)?

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I have written a program in C to convert a floating point number [represented in binary](http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm) (`1101.11`) into a decimal (`13.75`).

However, I cannot seem to get the correct value out of the algorithm.

What is the correct method for converting a binary floating point number into a decimal?

I am using Dev CPP compiler (32 bit). The algorithm is defined below:

```
void b2d(double p, double q )
{
   double rem, dec=0, main, f, i, t=0;

   /* integer part operation */    
   while ( p >= 1 )
   {
     rem = (int)fmod(p, 10);
     p = (int)(p / 10);
     dec = dec + rem * pow(2, t);
     t++;
   }

   /* fractional part operation */
   t = 1; //assigning '1' to use 't' in new operation
   while( q > 0 )
   {
     main = q * 10;
     q = modf(main, &i); //extration of frational part(q) and integer part(i)
     dec = dec+i*pow(2, -t);
     t++;
   }

   printf("\nthe decimal value=%lf\n",dec); //prints the final output
}

int main()
{
   double bin, a, f;

   printf("Enter binary number to convert:\n");
   scanf("%lf",&bin);

   /* separation of integer part and decimal part */
   a = (int)bin;
   f = bin - a;       
   b2d(a, f); // function calling for conversion

   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't really fit the Stackoverflow format. It's basically "Theres a bug in my code, can you find it." rather than "Here's this thing that's not working as expected". Try to reduce the specificity of your question and create a minimum test case. There's a very valid question here if you can reword it a little.

Comment: Your problem is that 1101.11 isn't representable as a `double`. You get (unless you have uncommon `double`s) `1101.109999999999899955582804977893829345703125`. And that destroys your algorithm.

Comment: `I have gone through the code many time` - looking at it, or stepping with a debugger? Take a look at what value is *actually* read in by the `scanf()` into `bin`. I bet you it's not *exactly* 1101.11

Comment: @brice I've improved the format a little; is this ok now?

Comment: @BiswajitPaul Have edited it a little too, hopefully this will be clearer :)

Comment: your fractional part conversion is not right

Comment: @DanielFischer has the right answer. Rather than reading it in as a double, read it in as a string (sequence of ascii characters) and then work out what binary number that represents.

Comment: @Mike: yes its not exactly 1101.11 but rather 1101.110000

And when I print those two values after extracting integer part and fractional part, printf gives me correct value as expected..

eg. 1101.000000 and 0.110000

and one thing to say:
While operating on 0.110000,
in while loop, the second iteration gives me wrong value of variables and that leads me to the exception.

Comment: @DanielFischer then I've to convert those char value to int substructing '0'..am I right?

Comment: The default precision of `printf("%f", ...)` is 6 decimal places. If there is imprecision below the 6th decimal place (hint: there is), you won't see it like this. Try `printf("%.24f\n", bin)'` right after you scan it in.

Comment: Yup, `digit - '0'` converts a character that is a decimal digit to the corresponding `int` value.

Comment: @Useless, yes, the value is not that one I've entered; I've got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of code behaves abnormally: I added some simple print statement

```
  while(q>0)
  {
     double i;
     main=q*10.0;
     q=modf(main, &i); //extration of frational part(q) and integer part(i)
     cout << "main = " << main << " frac part " << q << " int part " << i << endl;
     cin.get();
     dec=dec+i*pow(2,-t);
     t++;
  }
```

When  you input 1101.11, the following output shown:

```
Enter binary number to convert(e.g: 1101.11 which will be 13.75 in decimal):
1101.11
bin in main 1101.11
p  1101 q 0.11

//inside the above while loop code
main = 1.1 frac part 0.1 int part 1
main = 1 frac part 1 int part 0  //^^^^^Error, given main=1, it should output integer part 1, fraction part 0
main = 10 frac part 1 int part 9  //^^^^^same strange error here, it should exit while already
```

So you got wrong result.  I tested `modf` separately with input 1, it gave correct result.

So my guess is that you are reading the binary number as double, then tries to convert this double to binary back. There might be something going on under the hood for the precision of number though it shows that it is `1101.11`. As suggested by @Useless, You may need to read the number as a string, figure out the substring before and after the decimal point `.` Then convert this two part into decimal separately.

Comment: [You may need to read the number as a string, figure out the substring before and after the decimal point . Then convert this two part into decimal separately](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15769250/140264)

Answer (score 5):

You are not, as you believe, reading "1101.11" as a *floating point number represented in binary*. You are reading it as a *base-10 floating point number converted into an IEEE double-precision floating-point value*, and **then** trying to change the base.

The inherent imprecision of this intermediate step is the reason for your problem.

A better approach, as suggested by Vicky, is to:

1. read "1101.11" as a string or line of text
2. convert the whole and fractional parts (`whole=b1101=13` and `numerator=b11=3`, `denominator=4`)
3. re-combine these into `whole + numerator/denominator = 13.75`

Comment: If the binary number is originally not in string format, is there any way I could convert it to string? The binary number is originally fed from a fpga block say14 bits, with msb as the sign bit, the following 6 bits are the magnitude for integer and the last 6 bits are the magnitude for fractional ...

Comment: You should probably ask this as a new question - you'll get much better answers than will fit in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

The following will work as expected:

Output:

```
➤ gcc bin2dec.c -lm -o bin2dec && bin2dec
1101.11 -> 13.750000
1101 -> 13.000000
1101. -> 13.000000
.11 -> 0.750000
```

Code (`bin2dec.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double convert(const char binary[]){
  int bi,i;
  int len = 0;
  int dot = -1;
  double result = 0;

  for(bi = 0; binary[bi] != '\0'; bi++){
    if(binary[bi] == '.'){
      dot = bi;
    }
    len++;
  }
  if(dot == -1)
    dot=len;

  for(i = dot; i >= 0 ; i--){
    if (binary[i] == '1'){
      result += (double) pow(2,(dot-i-1));
    }
  }
  for(i=dot; binary[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if (binary[i] == '1'){
      result += 1.0/(double) pow(2.0,(double)(i-dot));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
   char  bin[] = "1101.11";
   char  bin1[] = "1101";
   char  bin2[] = "1101.";
   char  bin3[] = ".11";

   printf("%s -> %f\n",bin, convert(bin)); 
   printf("%s -> %f\n",bin1, convert(bin1)); 
   printf("%s -> %f\n",bin2, convert(bin2)); 
   printf("%s -> %f\n",bin3, convert(bin3)); 

   return 0;
}
```

### Explanation

The above code works by first finding the index of the decimal point in the number.

Once that is known, it walks the string both backwards and forwards from this index, adding the appropriate value to the `result` variable.

The first loop walks backwards from the decimal point and accumulates the powers of 2 if the character is `1`. It takes the distance from the decimal point as the power of two, minus one for the indexing to be correct. Ie, it accumulates :

```
pow(2,<distance-from-decimal-point>)
```

The loop stops when the index reaches the beginning of the string.

The second loop walks forward until the end of the string, and deals with the fractional part [as expected](http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm) it also uses the distance from the index, but this time accumulates fractional parts:

```
1/pow(2,<distance-from-decimal-point>)
```

### Worked out example:

```
1101.11 = 1101 + 0.11

1101 = 1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 = 8 + 4 + 0 + 1 = 13

0.11 = 1/(2^1) + 1/(2^2) = 0.5 + 0.25 = 0.75

1101.11 = 13.75
```

Beware of malformed input. "10gsh.9701072.67812" will give you a result. It won't mean much :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... I am wondering if this code can be used to check for negative value? I did try with a binary string of 11111101.11 and it gives the output of 253.75... What are the modifications I need to do in order to read a negative value? If the binary number is originally not in string format, is there any way I could convert it to string? The binary number is originally fed from a fpga block say14 bits, with msb as the sign bit, the following 6 bits are the magnitude for integer and the last 6 bits are the magnitude for fractional ...