# Convert binary ( integer and fraction) from VHDL to decimal, negative value in C code

Tags: string, binary, fpga, signed

I have a 14-bit data that is fed from FPGA in vhdl, The NIos II processor reads the 14-bit data from FPGA and do some processing tasks, where Nios II system is programmed in C code

The 14-bit data can be positive, zero or negative. In Altera compiler, I can only define the data to be 8,16 or 32. So I define this to be 16 bit data.

First, I need to check if the data is negative, if it is negative, I need to pad the first two MSB to be bit '1' so the system detects it as negative value instead of positive value.

Second, I need to compute the real value of this binary representation into a decimal value of BOTH integer and fraction.

I learned from this link ([Correct algorithm to convert binary floating point "1101.11" into decimal (13.75)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767758/correct-algorithm-to-convert-binary-floating-point-1101-11-into-decimal-13-75)) that I could convert a binary (consists of both integer and fraction) to decimal values.

To be specified, I am able to use this code quoted from this link ([Correct algorithm to convert binary floating point "1101.11" into decimal (13.75)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767758/correct-algorithm-to-convert-binary-floating-point-1101-11-into-decimal-13-75)) , reproduced as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double convert(const char binary[]){
  int bi,i;
  int len = 0;
  int dot = -1;
  double result = 0;

  for(bi = 0; binary[bi] != '\0'; bi++){
    if(binary[bi] == '.'){
      dot = bi;
    }
    len++;
  }
  if(dot == -1)
    dot=len;

  for(i = dot; i >= 0 ; i--){
    if (binary[i] == '1'){
      result += (double) pow(2,(dot-i-1));
    }
  }
  for(i=dot; binary[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if (binary[i] == '1'){
      result += 1.0/(double) pow(2.0,(double)(i-dot));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
   char  bin[] = "1101.11";
   char  bin1[] = "1101";
   char  bin2[] = "1101.";
   char  bin3[] = ".11";

   printf("%s -> %f\n",bin, convert(bin)); 
   printf("%s -> %f\n",bin1, convert(bin1)); 
   printf("%s -> %f\n",bin2, convert(bin2)); 
   printf("%s -> %f\n",bin3, convert(bin3)); 

   return 0;
}
```

I am wondering if this code can be used to check for negative value? I did try with a binary string of 11111101.11 and it gives the output of 253.75...

I have two questions:

1. What are the modifications I need to do in order to read a negative value?

I know that I can do the bit shift (as below) to check if the msb is 1, if it is 1, I know it is negative value...

```
if (14bit_data & 0x2000) //if true, it is negative value
```

The issue is, since it involves fraction part (but not only integer), it confused me a bit if the method still works...

2. If the binary number is originally not in string format, is there any way I could convert it to string? The binary number is originally fed from a fpga block written in VHDL say, 14 bits, with msb as the sign bit, the following 6 bits are the magnitude for integer and the last 6 bits are the magnitude for fractional part. I need the decimal value in C code for Altera Nios II processor.

Comment: You mention FPGA. In which langage are you writing you code ? VHDL ? VLOG ? or is it software code written in C by example ?

Comment: @Quicky, thanks for your reply, sorry for not making it clear, it is vhdl in fpga and C code in Altera Nios II system (will edit it in the main post for clarification)

Comment: But here you question concern C code ? I don`t understand what is you question exactly ?  Do you just want to check if this is a negative value ? or compute the real value of this binary represenation assuming this is a signed number ?

Comment: The 14-bit data is fed from FPGA in vhdl, the NIos II processor reads the 14-bit data from FPGA and do some processing tasks, where Nios II system is programmed in C code

Comment: Ok that's clear. And so what is the goal of the code ?

Comment: Yes, I want to compute the real value of this binary represenation assuming this is a signed number. The 14-bit data is in this format, msb for signed bit, the following 6 bits represent the magnitude of integer part, the last 6 bits represent the magnitude of fraction part. How could I do that?

Comment: The 14-bit data can be positive, zero or negative. In Altera compiler, I can only define the data to be 8,16 or 32. So I define this to be 16 bit data.  First, I need to check if the data is negative, if it is negative, I need to pad the first two msb to be 1 so the system detects it as negative instead of positive value. Second, I need to compute the real value of this binary representation into a decimal value of BOTH integer and fraction

Comment: I was thinking to be able to answer if binary representation was [Two Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) or [One complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) but it seems to be something else more exotic...

Comment: @Quicky, sorry I don't quite understand your last comment... forgive me if my question is too simple, but I just need a hint for me to start working on it, thank you for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
float convert14BitsToFloat(int16_t in)
{
    /* Sign-extend in, since it is 14 bits */
    if (in & 0x2000) in |= 0xC000;

    /* convert to float with 6 decimal places (64 = 2^6) */
    return (float)in / 64.0f;
}
```

To convert any number to string, I would use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/). Be aware it may significantly increase the size of your application. If you don't need the float and what to keep a small application, you should make your own conversion function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
 I need to compute the real value of this binary representation into a decimal value of BOTH integer and fraction.

For example, "in" is 15282 (0011 1011 1011 0010), but it is not the real value, how to make sure I will get the value as -30.750015 instead of 15282?

The 14-bit-data is defined as follow: with msb as the sign bit, the following 6 bits are the magnitude for integer and the last 6 bits are the magnitude for fractional part.

Comment: This is what this code does, convert a signed 14 bits with 6 bits fractional part into a float, it deals with sign just fine. Note that you seem confused, 1 bit for sign + 6 bits integer + 6 bits fractionnal is 13 bits, not the 14 bits you input. My code assumes 7 bits integer part and 6 bits fractionnal. Also, I'm quite unsure how 15282 should equal -30.75. 15282 is -1102, which gives -17.21875 (the same as my code)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am wrong for the total bits. With 7 bits integer part and 6 bits fractional, do you mind to explain how to get -17.21875? I am sorry for the simple question. When I run the code, I get 1006.781250, I think I missed out some important points, sorry

Comment: First, if the value is negative, get the positive value. For 15282 using 2's complement, this is 2^14-15282 = 1102. 1102 in binary (with decimal point) is 10001.001110, the integer part is easy: 10001 = 17. The fractional part is 1/8+1/16+1/32 = 0.21875, the total => -17.21875.

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply... I now understand how to get the value -17.21875 manually, but I dont understand how the C code you posted can be used to display this value (-17.21875) when I run the code? sorry for my poor understanding

Comment: Try this: `printf("%f\n", convert14BitsToFloat(15282));` My code convert to a full signed 16 bits (using 2's complement), than convert the whole integer to float. Since there are 6 bits for fractional part, you divide that by 2^6 to shift the 6 fractional bits to the right of the decimal point. Try it, -1102/64 = -17.21875

Comment: @users2563812 : if you execute the code of Jonathan in & 0x2000 is true so in |= 0xC000 is executed so in become 0xFBB2. this value is 64434 if in is considered as an unsigned which lead to 1006.781250 when divided by 64. In case it is a 16 bits signed integer this equal to -1102 which lead to the expected result -17.21875 when divided by 64 so it means that in your code in is not declared as a signed integer or the signed integer is coded on more than 16 bits and in this case you should modify the OR mask that extend the width of the number to keep the sign

Comment: I did set it as signed integer and I keep getting this value 1006.781250 instead of -17.21875, I will need to think what is wrong with my code.

#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{  
 float aa =convert14BitsToFloat(15282);
 printf("%f\n",aa ); }

float convert14BitsToFloat(signed int in)
{
    /* Sign-extend in, since it is 14 bits */
    if (in & 0x2000) in |= 0xC000;

    /* convert to float with 6 decimal places (64 = 2^6) */
    return (float)in / 64.0f;
}

Comment: I suggest you use `int16_t` as in my code. It is defined in `#include <stdint.h>` and is guaranteed to be 16 bits signed.

Comment: Thank you both for valuable inputs, the reason I removed it is due to I having error with the int16_t while compiling it even though I have included the stdint.h library, I am using Altera Monitor Program to compile....

Comment: Try to use inttypes.h if it still not works the defaut signed int is certainly 32 bits so try if (in & 0x2000) in |= 0xFFFFC000;

Comment: Thanks both for valuable replies, I really appreciate... It is now working with the following code after I remove the function call by having only the main function, perhaps I missed something, but the following code works by giving the value -17.218750:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int main ()
{  int16_t in=15282;
 
if (in & 0x2000) in |= 0xC000;

    /* convert to float with 6 decimal places (64 = 2^6) */
    printf("%f", (float)in / 64.0f);

}

Answer (score 2):

**OK so I m focusing on the fact that you want to reuse the algorithm you mention at the beginning of your question and assume that the binary representation you have for your signed number is [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) but I`m not really sure according to your comments that the input you have is the same than the one used by the algorithm**

First pad the 2 MSB to have a 16 bit representation

```
16bit_data = (14_bit_data & 0x2000) ? ( 14_bit_data | 0xC000) : 14_bit_data ;
```

In case value is positive then value will remained unchanged and if negative this will be the correct two`s complement representation on 16bits.

For fractionnal part everything is the same compared to algorithm you mentionned in your question.
For integer part everything is the same except the treatment of MSB.
For unsigned number MSB (ie bit[15]) represents pow(2,15-6) ( 6 is the width of frationnal part ) whereas for signed number in Two`s complement representation it represents -pow(2,15-6) meaning that algorithm become

```
/* integer part operation */    
while(p >= 1)
{
  rem = (int)fmod(p, 10);
  p = (int)(p / 10);
  dec = dec + rem * pow(2, t) * (9 != t ? 1 : -1);
  ++t;
}
```

or said differently if you don`t want * operator

```
/* integer part operation */    
while(p >= 1)
{
  rem = (int)fmod(p, 10);
  p = (int)(p / 10);
  if( 9 != t)
  {
     dec = dec + rem * pow(2, t);
  }
  else
  {
     dec = dec - rem * pow(2, t);
  }
  ++t;
}
```

For the second algorithm that you mention, considering you format if dot == 11 and i == 0 we are at MSB ( 10 integer bits followed by dot) so the code become

```
for(i = dot - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
   if (binary[i] == '1')
   {
       if(11 != dot || i)
       {
           result += (double) pow(2,(dot-i-1));
       }
       else
       {
           // result -= (double) pow(2,(dot-i-1));
           // Due to your number format i == 0 and dot == 11 so
          result -= 512
       }
   }
}
```

**WARNING : in brice algorithm the input is character string like "11011.101" whereas according to your description you have an integer input so I`m not sure that this algorithm is suited to your case**

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to understand... I was able to use the code at the bottom of the page (author brice) in the link I mentioned earlier but NOT the one by thread starter due to the compiler not supporting fmod, I know this is demanding, could you please point out for me the changes needed for the integer part in the following code:

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code or information, you will be able to format in a better way

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes, I have add the code and source it properly in the original post as I couldn't do that in comment. Could you please point out for me the changes needed for the integer part in the code

Comment: If I understand correctly, the equivalent changes to your previous post: Please correct me if I am wrong

 for(i = dot-6; i >= 0 ; i--){
    if (binary[i] == '1'){
      result += (double) pow(2,(dot-i-1));
    }
  }

Comment: This will not take in account the sign bit as you just consider integer part. I updated my answer for brice algorithm

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean. YOu are right, my input is in integer format originally when I read the data from fpga block, and display it as integer .. I was thinking of converting this input to binary string, do you think this additional step is not needed? If I skip this step, how do I access one by one bit? Sorry for the question